Apple Pay - Authorize.net returns error 265 while payment processor is Chase Paymentech
Authorize.net returns error 265 to Apple Pay transaction
While integrating Apple Pay + Authorize.Net into Magento 2.4.5-p5, I'm running into an issue the payment transaction is not able to create and Authorize.Net returns error # 265, error message "This transaction cannot be processed.". The payment processor of Authorize.Net account is "Chase Paymentech". However, it's able to create transaction in my sandbox Authorize.net account which processor is "First Data Nashville". The code implementation is same and the transaction request is same. The most suspicious I guess are the payment processor of Authorize.Net account and the Bank account tied to Authorize.Net. But I could not find any solution yet. I'm stuck in this issue for a while and appreciate any idea or recommendation to either fix or narrow down the issue.
Attach payment request and response below.
Request
array (
    'payload_type' => 'createTransactionRequest',
    'merchantAuthentication' => 
    array (
      'name' => 'LOGIN_ID',
      'transactionKey' => 'TRANSACTION_KEY',
    ),
    'transactionRequest' => 
    array (
      'transactionType' => 'authCaptureTransaction',
      'amount' => '24.85',
      'payment' => 
      array (
        'opaqueData' => 
        array (
          'dataDescriptor' => 'COMMON.APPLE.INAPP.PAYMENT',
          'dataValue' => 'eyJkYXRhIjoiaG8rMHFwdElvYlFXVTBBRncvbXY1eVJHZ2lQMEd6NFczSDVUZFJjcUJmNVJjS1poaXJtZHNiTXpMblZybmh0K1k0M0NUcDFGK3dVdW9YdmhtWkRPUkhNYnJRdU5ZUDVrOGFFSjZ1WWZGVTRwK09BQ0ljWTFNZlVaaW5NbGpBWVlBRWw3WUVJT0JkU21KOWYrSWJ2dEUxRFNxV0F1V0RPb29KMnpPRWxlVjZtOXVzSXpYTVlpYXdTMXcyS3lWT2lSNWNGZ2pKb0FrR2ZuS0VqRFY3M2l1Wmo4TXVYc0o1OFNBdHAxSlFFR2hCWmpGTXhGU0Y2MjNrU1dSaGZVcGQ0WnFRMDJmblhGQkY0WUJPTExjOEVCZHlKajcxM2pTcjFEN05paEoxV3FBL2RkYVBQMm5UZjFwS2pMbFlINDhHbXd0NlZWc3RqSzZFM2NXZGxPQmRmZVlYdUpQRHg1RGxaZUJvVTd5VWpVTXVzNVI3L25XSmVjNjl4T3ZMMDdtRE92Mmo4NkNZOXBoVWx2REJzWWNIV0YrQnRYb2V6NFNpZnRjcGFqMEZDdUNkST0iLCJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiJNSUFHQ1NxR1NJYjNEUUVIQXFDQU1JQUNBUUV4RFRBTEJnbGdoa2dCWlFNRUFnRXdnQVlKS29aSWh2Y05BUWNCQUFDZ2dEQ0NBK013Z2dPSW9BTUNBUUlDQ0JaalRJc09NRmNYTUFvR0NDcUdTTTQ5QkFNQ01Ib3hMakFzQmdOVkJBTU1KVUZ3Y0d4bElFRndjR3hwWTJGMGFXOXVJRWx1ZEdWbmNtRjBhVzl1SUVOQklDMGdSek14SmpBa0JnTlZCQXNNSFVGd2NHeGxJRU5sY25ScFptbGpZWFJwYjI0Z1FYVjBhRzl5YVhSNU1STXdFUVlEVlFRS0RBcEJjSEJzWlNCSmJtTXVNUXN3Q1FZRFZRUUdFd0pWVXpBZUZ3MHlOREEwTWpreE56UTNNamRhRncweU9UQTBNamd4TnpRM01qWmFNRjh4SlRBakJnTlZCQU1NSEdWall5MXpiWEF0WW5KdmEyVnlMWE5wWjI1ZlZVTTBMVkJTVDBReEZEQVNCZ05WQkFzTUMybFBVeUJUZVhOMFpXMXpNUk13RVFZRFZRUUtEQXBCY0hCc1pTQkpibU11TVFzd0NRWURWUVFHRXdKVlV6QlpNQk1HQnlxR1NNNDlBZ0VHQ0NxR1NNNDlBd0VIQTBJQUJNSVZkKzNyMXNleUlZOW8zWENRb1NHTng3QzlieXdvUFlSZ2xkbEs5S1ZCRzROQ0R0Z1I4MEIrZ3pNZkhGVEQ5K3N5SU5hNjFkVHY5SktKaVQ1OER4T2pnZ0lSTUlJQ0RUQU1CZ05WSFJNQkFmOEVBakFBTUI4R0ExVWRJd1FZTUJhQUZDUHlTY1JQaytUdkorYkU5aWhzUDZLNy9TNUxNRVVHQ0NzR0FRVUZCd0VCQkRrd056QTFCZ2dyQmdFRkJRY3dBWVlwYUhSMGNEb3ZMMjlqYzNBdVlYQndiR1V1WTI5dEwyOWpjM0F3TkMxaGNIQnNaV0ZwWTJFek1ESXdnZ0VkQmdOVkhTQUVnZ0VVTUlJQkVEQ0NBUXdHQ1NxR1NJYjNZMlFGQVRDQi9qQ0J3d1lJS3dZQkJRVUhBZ0l3Z2JZTWdiTlNaV3hwWVc1alpTQnZiaUIwYUdseklHTmxjblJwWm1sallYUmxJR0o1SUdGdWVTQndZWEowZVNCaGMzTjFiV1Z6SUdGalkyVndkR0Z1WTJVZ2IyWWdkR2hsSUhSb1pXNGdZWEJ3YkdsallXSnNaU0J6ZEdGdVpHRnlaQ0IwWlhKdGN5QmhibVFnWTI5dVpHbDBhVzl1Y3lCdlppQjFjMlVzSUdObGNuUnBabWxqWVhSbElIQnZiR2xqZVNCaGJtUWdZMlZ5ZEdsbWFXTmhkR2x2YmlCd2NtRmpkR2xqWlNCemRHRjBaVzFsYm5SekxqQTJCZ2dyQmdFRkJRY0NBUllxYUhSMGNEb3ZMM2QzZHk1aGNIQnNaUzVqYjIwdlkyVnlkR2xtYVdOaGRHVmhkWFJvYjNKcGRIa3ZNRFFHQTFVZEh3UXRNQ3N3S2FBbm9DV0dJMmgwZEhBNkx5OWpjbXd1WVhCd2JHVXVZMjl0TDJGd2NHeGxZV2xqWVRNdVkzSnNNQjBHQTFVZERnUVdCQlNVVjl0djFYU0Job21KZGk5K1Y0VUg1NXRZSkRBT0JnTlZIUThCQWY4RUJBTUNCNEF3RHdZSktvWklodmRqWkFZZEJBSUZBREFLQmdncWhrak9QUVFEQWdOSkFEQkdBaUVBeHZBanl5WVV1ekE0aUtGaW1ENGFrL0VGYjFENmVNMjV1a3lpUWN3VTRsNENJUUMrUE5EZjBXSkg5a2xFZFRnT25VVENLS0VJa0tPaDNISkxpMHk0aUpnWXZEQ0NBdTR3Z2dKMW9BTUNBUUlDQ0VsdEw3ODZtTnFYTUFvR0NDcUdTTTQ5QkFNQ01HY3hHekFaQmdOVkJBTU1Fa0Z3Y0d4bElGSnZiM1FnUTBFZ0xTQkhNekVtTUNRR0ExVUVDd3dkUVhCd2JHVWdRMlZ5ZEdsbWFXTmhkR2x2YmlCQmRYUm9iM0pwZEhreEV6QVJCZ05WQkFvTUNrRndjR3hsSUVsdVl5NHhDekFKQmdOVkJBWVRBbFZUTUI0WERURTBNRFV3TmpJek5EWXpNRm9YRFRJNU1EVXdOakl6TkRZek1Gb3dlakV1TUN3R0ExVUVBd3dsUVhCd2JHVWdRWEJ3YkdsallYUnBiMjRnU1c1MFpXZHlZWFJwYjI0Z1EwRWdMU0JITXpFbU1DUUdBMVVFQ3d3ZFFYQndiR1VnUTJWeWRHbG1hV05oZEdsdmJpQkJkWFJvYjNKcGRIa3hFekFSQmdOVkJBb01Da0Z3Y0d4bElFbHVZeTR4Q3pBSkJnTlZCQVlUQWxWVE1Ga3dFd1lIS29aSXpqMENBUVlJS29aSXpqMERBUWNEUWdBRThCY1JoQm5YWklYVkdsNGxnUWQyNklDaTc5NTdyazNnamZ4TGsrRXpWdFZtV3pXdUl0Q1hkZzBpVG51NkNQMTJGODZJeTNhN1puQyt5T2dwaFA5VVJhT0I5ekNCOURCR0JnZ3JCZ0VGQlFjQkFRUTZNRGd3TmdZSUt3WUJCUVVITUFHR0ttaDBkSEE2THk5dlkzTndMbUZ3Y0d4bExtTnZiUzl2WTNOd01EUXRZWEJ3YkdWeWIyOTBZMkZuTXpBZEJnTlZIUTRFRmdRVUkvSkp4RStUNU84bjVzVDJLR3cvb3J2OUxrc3dEd1lEVlIwVEFRSC9CQVV3QXdFQi96QWZCZ05WSFNNRUdEQVdnQlM3c042aFdET0ltcVNLbWQ2K3ZldXYyc3NrcXpBM0JnTlZIUjhFTURBdU1DeWdLcUFvaGlab2RIUndPaTh2WTNKc0xtRndjR3hsTG1OdmJTOWhjSEJzWlhKdmIzUmpZV2N6TG1OeWJEQU9CZ05WSFE4QkFmOEVCQU1DQVFZd0VBWUtLb1pJaHZkalpBWUNEZ1FDQlFBd0NnWUlLb1pJemowRUF3SURad0F3WkFJd09zOXlnMUVXbWJHRyt6WERWc3Bpdi9RWDdka1BkVTJpanI3eG5JRmVRcmVKK0pqM20xbWZtTlZCRFkrZDZjTCtBakF5TGRWRUliQ2pCWGRzWGZNNE81Qm4vUmQ4TENGdGxrL0djbW1DRW05VStIcDlHNW5MbXdtSklXRUdtUThKa2gwQUFER0NBWWt3Z2dHRkFnRUJNSUdHTUhveExqQXNCZ05WQkFNTUpVRndjR3hsSUVGd2NHeHBZMkYwYVc5dUlFbHVkR1ZuY21GMGFXOXVJRU5CSUMwZ1J6TXhKakFrQmdOVkJBc01IVUZ3Y0d4bElFTmxjblJwWm1sallYUnBiMjRnUVhWMGFHOXlhWFI1TVJNd0VRWURWUVFLREFwQmNIQnNaU0JKYm1NdU1Rc3dDUVlEVlFRR0V3SlZVd0lJRm1OTWl3NHdWeGN3Q3dZSllJWklBV1VEQkFJQm9JR1RNQmdHQ1NxR1NJYjNEUUVKQXpFTEJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkJ3RXdIQVlKS29aSWh2Y05BUWtGTVE4WERUSTBNRFl5TkRBek1qSXpNRm93S0FZSktvWklodmNOQVFrME1Sc3dHVEFMQmdsZ2hrZ0JaUU1FQWdHaENnWUlLb1pJemowRUF3SXdMd1lKS29aSWh2Y05BUWtFTVNJRUlIbTdoVFNQVUVkMWV0cTkyc0tYZDRvYlkwUWxEbzNIb1ZCZjNNUVdrTkdOTUFvR0NDcUdTTTQ5QkFNQ0JFZ3dSZ0loQUpEZWZESmhtNlg3Tkg1UTVwTGs2a3BqbkJYeHBpQVNBTm1SbUZWZVoxdTNBaUVBcTl4dE9pQ1VnT0lrMFRicmdSaThEU2s5Z0k1bzVpclJEaVJib3lMZ1NvMEFBQUFBQUFBPSIsImhlYWRlciI6eyJwdWJsaWNLZXlIYXNoIjoieTR4SzdWSU1RRGJRYkJGWVpZKzF0disvbFROeFVDNWhFZW5CUmtoa3pJbz0iLCJlcGhlbWVyYWxQdWJsaWNLZXkiOiJNRmt3RXdZSEtvWkl6ajBDQVFZSUtvWkl6ajBEQVFjRFFnQUUxSno0K05yQnFianpkQWQ2RmE3NmQzNDI3NzV5VGxHME5rK1g2R1BBR2x6M3pSTXFqTDYxZHJIUDM5NUE3cW9GVkEzT2pvMHI0aG1nalY5eENGRHR6UT09IiwidHJhbnNhY3Rpb25JZCI6IjQ5YWM5NmQwYmEyM2ZmODBiOWQ5ZWI0YTZmYTg3N2I4MWZlYjgxZGMzNGIzMjBiZDRjNzhkM2M2NjIwOTQzNzYifSwidmVyc2lvbiI6IkVDX3YxIn0=',
        ),
      ),
      'solution' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'AAA102993',
      ),
      'order' => 
      array (
        'invoiceNumber' => '3000660812',
      ),
      'poNumber' => NULL,
      'customer' => 
      array (
        'id' => NULL,
        'email' => 'web-qa@currentinc.com',
      ),
      'billTo' => 
      array (
        'firstName' => 'Tester',
        'lastName' => 'Tester',
        'company' => '',
        'address' => '6603 Snowy Range Dr',
        'city' => 'Colorado Springs',
        'state' => 'CO',
        'zip' => '80923-5190',
        'country' => 'US',
      ),
      'shipTo' => 
      array (
        'firstName' => 'Tester',
        'lastName' => 'Tester',
        'company' => '',
        'address' => '6603 Snowy Range Dr',
        'city' => 'Colorado Springs',
        'state' => 'CO',
        'zip' => '80923-5190',
        'country' => 'US',
      ),
      'customerIP' => '207.109.165.210',
      'retail' => 
      array (
        'marketType' => '0',
        'deviceType' => '8',
      ),
      'userFields' => 
      array (
        'userField' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'transactionType',
            'value' => 'authCaptureTransaction',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )

Response
{
  "transactionResponse": {
    "responseCode": "3",
    "authCode": "",
    "avsResultCode": "P",
    "cvvResultCode": "",
    "cavvResultCode": "",
    "transId": "0",
    "refTransID": "",
    "transHash": "",
    "testRequest": "0",
    "accountNumber": "XXXX0546",
    "accountType": "Visa",
    "errors": [
      {
        "errorCode": "265",
        "errorText": "This transaction cannot be processed."
      }
    ],
    "userFields": [
      {
        "name": "transactionType",
        "value": "authCaptureTransaction"
      }
    ],
    "transHashSha2": "35D391DDCBFE2706C5F5B630735C30725E91916F2A3F1FABBFBF13D35329EE338B4562E0314AA77BE92E795A5936A9B717ADC0020B40DECB8813ADF12CAC02EC",
    "SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator": 0
  },
  "messages": {
    "resultCode": "Error",
    "message": [
      {
        "code": "E00027",
        "text": "The transaction was unsuccessful."
      }
    ]
  }
}

=================================
UPDATE
After reaching out Authorize.Net support, figured the root cause is the solution id is invalid for this transaction request. Removing it fixes the issue.
